# Connecting Windows Phone 8 Emulator (on VirtualBox) to Visual Studio (on host machine)

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have Visual Studio 2013 (running on the host machine - Windows 8.1 Single Language).

I was able to enable my hardware virtualization features and run the Windows Phone 8 emulator on a virtual machine (through Oracle VirtualBox).

I don't have Windows 8.1 Pro (and it costs money to upgrade), so I can't use Hyper-V.

So, I have the code running on my Visual Studio and an Emulator running on a VM in Oracle VirtualBox. Now, I want these two to connect so that the app can be seen on my emulator. But I can't find a way to do that. Can I do something (maybe connect the two on the same network and use the emulator as a device or something like that) in order to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: I code for WinCE devices daily.  I know you can deploy your application over Ethernet and debug over Ethernet.  That could be an option.  But I don't see that listed as any of the options under a WP project.  So I guess you can google debugging over Ethernet and see if that returns any results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Application Deployment Tool.

Usually found here:

`D:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe`

You would have to get your compiled XAP to the virtual machine, using a shared folder between host and virtual machine for example.
Then select the device (Emulator) and the XAP and hit deploy.

I hope this helps!